# AWS Cloudformation - security group ids list export and import - SecurityGroupIds not valid

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Im working with 2 nested stacks. I need to use security group ids exported from NestedA in NestedB. The exported security group ids are to be used in a SecurityGroupIds property in NestedB based on conditions.

However cloudformation returns error: Property validation failure: [Value of property {/LaunchTemplateData/SecurityGroupIds/0} does not match type {String}]

The following are snippets of what I have tried:

**NestedA export**

```
Outputs:
    SG1
    Value: !Join
    - ','
    - - !Ref securitygroup1
      - !Ref securitygroup2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-SG1

    SG2
    Value: !Join
    - ','
    - - !Ref securitygroup3
      - !Ref securitygroup4
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-SG2
```

**ParentStack**

```
Resources:
  ...
  launchtemplate:
    Type: AWS::Cloudformation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://s3/nestedB.yaml
      ...
      SG1:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-SG1
      SG2:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-SG2
```

**NestedB import**

```
Parameters:
  SG1
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>

  SG2
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>

Resources:
  launchtemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
      ...
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          !If
          - Condition1
          -
            - !Ref SG1
            - !Ref SG2
          - !If
            - Condition2
            - 
              - !Ref SG1
            - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Ive also tried importing each of the security groups directly/individually into NestedB with no success ie:

**NestedA export**

```
Outputs:
  securitygroup1:
    Value: !Ref securitygroup1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup1

  securitygroup2:
    Value: !Ref securitygroup2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup2

  securitygroup3:
    Value: !Ref securitygroup3
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup3

  securitygroup4:
    Value: !Ref securitygroup4
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup4
```

**NestedB import**

```
Resources:
  launchtemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
      ...
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          !If
          - Condition1
          -
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup1
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup2
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup3
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup4
          - !If
            - Condition2
            - 
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup1
             - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVpcStackName}-securitygroup2
            - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Whats the error Im making?

**Edit:** I have tried @marcin suggestion but still get the error:

```
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/LaunchTemplateData/SecurityGroupIds/0} does not match type {String}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>`, please use [CommaDelimitedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

Also your `SG1` is a list of SGs. You have to use [Fn::Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) to get individual SG values from the list.

Comment: thanks. ive now tried this but still does not accept?

Comment: got this to work - following @marcin advise plus correcting tab spacing errors in the nested if conditions